# Which architecture is this machine code?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, machine-code

I dumped a ROM recently.

I tried to disassembled the machine code* for many architectures, but I always got assembly which, at best, looked like garbage.

Note: I can perfectly read the strings the the ROM dump.

*I have no proof this is really machine code.

Here is the beginning of the two write-protected sections:

```
    [000000] 00 40 02 0d 16 ef c3 60 01 d3 92 00 22 02 0d db  .@.....`...."...
    [000010] 8f 96 22 00 00 02 0e b1 90 3e 57 12 08 91 e4 ff  .."......>W.....
    [000020] fe fd fc 90 3e 5b 12 08 91 c0 96 75 96 03 e4 ff  ....>[.....u....
    [000030] 7e c0 fd fc 90 3e 57 12 08 27 c3 12 07 84 50 03  ~....>W..'....P.
    [000040] 02 00 a1 e4 fc fd fe 90 40 00 e4 f8 f9 fa e4 93  ........@.......
    [000050] 28 f8 e4 39 f9 a3 da f6 e8 2c fc e9 3d fd e4 3e  (..9.....,..=..>
    [000060] fe e5 83 70 e5 90 3e 5e e0 2c f0 90 3e 5d e0 3d  ...p..>^.,..>].=
    [000070] f0 90 3e 5c e0 3e f0 90 3e 5b e0 34 00 f0 e5 96  ..>\.>..>[.4....
    [000080] 04 f5 96 90 3e 57 12 08 0b c3 ef 94 00 ff ee 94  ....>W..........
    [000090] c0 fe ed 94 00 fd ec 94 00 fc 90 3e 57 12 08 91  ...........>W...
    [0000a0] 02 00 2c 90 3e 59 e0 f9 a3 e0 f8 90 3e 5b e0 ff  ..,.>Y......>[..
    [0000b0] a3 e0 fe a3 e0 fd a3 e0 fc 90 40 00 e8 49 60 15  ..........@..I`.
    [0000c0] 18 b8 ff 01 19 e4 93 2c fc e4 3d fd e4 3e fe e4  .......,..=..>..
    [0000d0] 3f ff a3 80 e7 90 3e 5b ef f0 a3 ee f0 a3 ed f0  ?.....>[........
    [0000e0] a3 ec f0 d0 96 90 3e 5b 12 08 0b 22 10 11 0b 12  ......>[..."....
    [0000f0] 0f 04 bf 0d 02 7f 0a 02 01 69 90 49 da e0 ff 22  ........i.I..."

    [040000] 90 3c db 12 24 2d 90 3c df 12 24 7c e4 7f 01 fe  .<..$-.<..$|...
    [040010] fd fc 12 23 9c e4 ff fe fd fc 90 3c db 12 23 d3  ...#.......<..#.
    [040020] d3 12 23 40 40 3f 90 3c df 12 24 45 c0 03 c0 02  ..#@@?.<..$E....
    [040030] c0 01 12 23 77 e4 7b 02 fa f9 f8 12 21 cb d0 01  ...#w.{.....!...
    [040040] d0 02 d0 03 12 23 9c 90 3c db 12 23 c7 ef 24 ff  .....#..<..#..$.
    [040050] ff ee 34 ff fe ed 34 ff fd ec 34 ff fc 90 3c db  ..4...4...4...<.
    [040060] 12 24 2d 80 b0 22 ef f4 60 05 7e 09 7f 01 22 90  .$-.."..`.~..".
    [040070] 37 55 e0 fd c3 94 80 40 05 7e 09 7f 03 22 af 05  7U.....@.~.."..
    [040080] e4 fc fd fe 12 17 51 ef 4e 60 01 22 e4 fe ff 22  ......Q.N`."..."
    [040090] 90 37 6d ef f0 c3 94 02 40 05 7e 09 7f 01 22 e4  .7m.....@.~..".
    [0400a0] 7f ff fe fd fc 90 37 6e 12 23 d3 d3 12 23 40 40  .....7n.#...#@@
    [0400b0] 02 80 61 90 37 6d e0 25 e0 25 e0 ff 74 0f 7e 00  ..a.7m.%.%..t.~.
    [0400c0] a8 07 08 80 05 c3 33 ce 33 ce d8 f9 ff ee 33 95  ......3.3.....3.
    [0400d0] e0 fd fc 90 37 6e 12 23 d3 12 22 f5 c0 04 c0 05  ....7n.#..".....
    [0400e0] c0 06 c0 07 90 37 6d e0 25 e0 25 e0 ff 74 0f 7e  .....7m.%.%..t.~
    [0400f0] 00 a8 07 08 80 05 c3 33 ce 33 ce d8 f9 fb aa 06  .......3.3......
```

Can you identify which architecture/endianess I should give to the disassembler?

Thanks;

Comment: Is it possible the ROM is interleaved? (In which case the odd bytes are in one ROM and the even bytes in another.)

Comment: @Jongware There is only one *visible* ROM. I cannot get the reference number of the main chip as the heat-sink is well-glued on it. I'll add in the question that strings are perfectly readable in the ROM dump.

Comment: Would you please upload somewhere the whole section files ?

Comment: Do you have FCC label on this device ? Once it was possible to find hardware specifications on FCC site if it is FCC approved.

Comment: And what about second section ? It looks much more promising.

Comment: Finally got the full dump (updated the previous link). Looks like it is a GS105Ev2. I do not have the casing, but the board has the right dimensions. Unfortunately, I could not find arch info on Netgear website. And no FCC ID.

Comment: OK, unfortunately I have no too much time for this, may be I'll continue this evening. For now I'd dig towards little endian MIPS: as far as I know some of netgear's network equipment uses MIPS architecture.

Comment: Since you already tried a lot, please add those to your post. No need to let others try the same list again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I found and how I found it.

### Finding strings

First, I examined the strings within the file to determine the type and model of equipment.  I did that visually, with a text editor (`vim`) after I had converted the file back to plain binary using `xxd`.

### Learning more about the device

Once I did that, I looked for images which show the inside of this product.  I found a few, which seemed to show that it's not much different than the usual 5-port unmanaged hub, with what appears to be a single Ethernet switch controller IC.  Unfortunately, the heatsink was still attached to the top of the chip of interest in the photos I found, so I tried a different approach.

### Process of elimination

There are maybe a dozen or so different vendors of Ethernet switch controllers, so I started searching for the prefixes of some of them within the binary image.  Jackpot!  I found the following strings: RTL8376B and RTL8367N.  Looking up the latter, the [manufacturer's web site](http://www.realtek.com/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=18&PFid=15&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=333) confirms that it is indeed a 5-port controller and that it contains an "Integrated 8051 microprocessor."

### Sample dump

Starting at offset 0x29200 which in your file, (chosen because it looked like it might be code and not data) I used `d52` to disassemble. An extract of the result is here:

```
    org 0
;
    mov r5,#0c2h
    mov dptr,#X3744
    lcall   X2445
    lcall   X2007
    xrl a,#1
    jz  X0012
    ljmp    X547d
;
X0012:  clr c
    mov r1,24h
    ajmp    X00c3
;
    cjne    r1,#0c3h,Xffbe
    addc    a,r2
    clr c
    cjne    r2,#12h,X003f
    inc @r1
    clr c
    cjne    r7,#0c3h,Xffa8
    rrc a
    rrc a
    anl a,#3
    jb  0c0h.3,Xffcb
    rr  a
    ljmp    X547d
;
    clr c
X0030:  mov r7,54h
    addc    a,r7
    clr c
    cjne    r7,#64h,X0039
    jz  X0041
X0039:  clr c
    mov r7,64h
    ajmp    X0060
```

For those familiar with 8051 programming, this is very plausible looking code, so it is indeed an 8051 derivative.  Good luck!